# Python Choice 3 arguments given

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, if you input

```
Type: Item
Total: 1,2 or 3
Item Type: Head
```

It "should" loop, choose from the specific Type's option list and then choose more if it can and make sure they're not duplicates.

```
import random

firstb = input('Type: ')
rarPropin = input('Total: ')
rarPropTotal = int(rarPropin)
first_random_item = input('Item Type: ')
item_slots = ['Head', 'Earring', 'Necklace']
HeadPropList = ['Stat1', 'Stat2', 'Stat3']
HeadWeight = [1, 0.5, 0.25]
EarPropList = ['Stat4', 'Stat5', 'Stat6']
EarWeight = [1, 0.5, 0.25]
NeckPropList = ['Stat7', 'Stat8', 'Stat9']
NeckWeight = [1, 0.5, 0.25]
ItemPropList = [HeadPropList, EarPropList, NeckPropList]
ItemWeightList = [HeadWeight, EarWeight, NeckWeight]
ItemProp = {Li: Prop for (Li, Prop) in zip(item_slots, ItemPropList)}
ItemWeight = {Li: Prop for (Li, Prop) in zip(item_slots, ItemWeightList)}
PropRoll = ItemProp[first_random_item]
Propstr = str(PropRoll)
PropWeight = ItemWeight[first_random_item]
Weightstr = str(PropWeight)

if firstb == "Item":
    S = []
    l = len(S)
    while l < rarPropTotal:
        c = random.choice([Propstr], [Weightstr])
        S.append(c)
        while S.contains(c):
            c = random.choice(Propstr, Weightstr)
            S.append(c)
    print("Property List: " + S)
```

But I keep getting the two following errors:

```
Error 1: TypeError: choice() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
Error 2: ValueError: The number of weights does not match the population
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking for.

Comment: There are several things that are wrong with your code at this point. First, neither of your while loops finishes because you are never getting rid of the loop condition. Also, list in Python does not have method "contains", you check for membership by "c in S" which evaluates to True if there is c in list S. Lastly, it is quite unclear what you actually want to do.

Comment: There is no call to `choices` in the code you show, which is what would raise the `ValueError` you mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code needs quite a lot of modification to work:

```
if firstb == "Item":
S = []
l = len(S)
while l < rarPropTotal:
    c = random.choice([Propstr, Weightstr])
    S.append(c)
    d = random.choice([Propstr, Weightstr])
    while d == c:
        d = random.choice([Propstr, Weightstr])
    S.append(d)
    l = l + 1
print("Property List: " + str(S))
```

To explain, first I added terminating condition of incrementing `l` at the end of outer while loop. Then I changed calls to `random.choice` to do a choice from a list of variables. Then I rewrote how you check for duplicates because your original approach was simply not doing that. `c` would always be in the `S` list because you added it there. You also need to cast the `S` list to a string when printing it out.

Sample output when the above code is run on your data:

```
> Type: Item
> Total: 3
> Item Type: Head

Property List: ['[1, 0.5, 0.25]', "['Stat1', 'Stat2', 'Stat3']", "['Stat1', 'Stat2', 'Stat3']", '[1, 0.5, 0.25]', '[1, 0.5, 0.25]', "['Stat1', 'Stat2', 'Stat3']"]
```

**EDIT:** Based on your comments, I think you'd rather do it like this:

```
if firstb == "Item":
    S = []
    l = len(S)
    while l < rarPropTotal:
        c = random.choices(PropRoll, PropWeight)[0] #[0] to avoid nested lists
        if c not in S:
            S.append(c)
            l = l + 1
    print("Property List: " + str(S))
```

This makes sure that there are no duplicates. The main change is that it is not using strings anymore as you were in your original code, because you can't really do a `random.choice` on a list which is encoded as a string. That's why it uses your `PropRoll` and `PropWeight` instead. Another thing is, if you want to use weights, you have to use `choices()` method, not `choice()`. The [former](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/random.html#random.choices) can use weights, the latter can not.

Sample output:

```
> Type: Item
> Total: 2
> Item Type: Head

Property List: ['Stat1', 'Stat3']
```

Comment: The Sample output isn't exactly what I am looking for. I was working towards it doing something like, if you 

`> Type: Item|

> Total: 2

> Item Type: Head


Property List: ['Stat1', 'Stat3']`

Essentially i don't want it to take the entirety of the list and output that but to choose one thing from the list and then put that into the S list

Comment: It's good to provide a sample output in a case like this as it helps others to understand what you are trying to achieve. I will try to offer a solution when I have more time.

Comment: Apologies, I am still new to this and the actual thing I am coding is so much bigger and interwoven that it was hard for me to pull this snippet out of it.

Also I don't know why it is outputting the weightings as an option. Cause random.choice is supposed to choose between Stat1, Stat2 and Stat3 while Weightstr is the weightings for those choices...

Comment: @B14d3r11 I see what happened here. You were using wrong method and wrong type as well. I also got rid of that duplicate checking as it was just adding more items than necessary. Have a look at my updated answer if this is now what you wanted. Also, if I might suggest, before getting into complex projects (as you mention this is one), it would be good for you to familiarize yourself with the language. Things go much easier then.

Comment: it works great! but the output is still a little... print("Property List: " + str(S)) is outputting 2 dozen different outputs like

`Property List: ['AGI']
Property List: ['MACC']
Property List: ['MDEF']
Property List: ['STR']
Property List: ['DEF']
Property List: ['MACC']
Property List: ['MP']
Property List: ['SPR']
Property List: ['MACC']
Property List: ['MACC']
Property List: ['DEF']`

And this was for a item with 1 property total

Comment: @B14d3r11 Well, it is impossible to help you with integrating the code without seeing how it was integrated. My best bet would be to check populate your code with print statements at each step and debug your code that way. Good luck and if my answers helped you I'll be glad if you upvote.

Comment: I don't have 15 rep yet to do upvotes but I will come back when I do and do that for you :)

Comment: @B14d3r11 Thanks but no need to worry about that, I asked mainly as it helps to differentiate between answers for future visitors. If you still struggle with integrating this into your code after debugging, notify me here in the comments and we can think of something.

Comment: I got it working after debugging! It was something really simple... I indented it 1 too many times so it was stuck in my for loop XD

Now I am attempting the next loop part, if you have a way for me to message you if I am struggling I'd appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

The `TypeError` happens because you are trying to pass two parameters to the `choice` method and it only takes one (plus the `self` parameter implicitly).

```
if firstb == "Item":
    S = []
    l = len(S)
    while l < rarPropTotal:
        c = random.choice([Propstr], [Weightstr])  # error happens here!
        S.append(c)
        while S.contains(c):
            c = random.choice(Propstr, Weightstr)  # and here
            S.append(c)
    print("Property List: " + S)
```

The lines should look like this:

```
c = random.choice([Propstr, Weightstr])
```

Comment: Yes, realised that, it's fixed now

Comment: This solves only 1 of many other problems that are present in OP's code.

Answer (score -1):

`choice` is a method, not a regular function (but a method of *what*? See below). As such, it takes an implicit argument as its first parameter and a sequence as its second. You are trying to provide the choices as separate arguments. The correct call is

```
c = random.choice([Propstr, Weightstr])
```

---

So why is `random.choice` a method? The `random` module creates an instance of `random.Random` to use for the module-level "functions", and `choice` is simply a bound method of that instance, not a function proper.

Near the bottom of `random.py`, you'll find:

```
# ...
_inst = Random()
# ...
choice = _inst.choice
```

which means the definition of `choice` isn't something like

```
def choice(seq):
    ...
```

but rather

```
def choice(self, seq):
    ...
```

That's what leads to the confusing message about `choice` expecting 2 arguments but being given 3.